# Determine if all 3 columns are all negative or positive, row by row

Tags: r, multiple-columns, rows

I have a dataset made of 3 columns and for each column, the values will vary between -1 and 1.

```
     A           B           C
0.0373      0.0373      0.0373
-0.0586     -0.0407     -0.1109
0.0458      0.0458      0.0458
0.0621      0.0621      0.0621
0.0452      0.0452      0.0452
```

I wish to identify all rows for which the sign for A, B and C is not the same. So for example, rows 2, 4 and 5 should be returned, because the sign of one of the column values is not the same as the other two.

I started out with this solution but was wondering if there might be something simpler and cleaner.

```
df$test = (df$A > 0 & df$B > 0  & df$C > 0)
df$test2 = (df$A < 0 & df$B < 0  & df$C < 0)

result = subset(df,df$test == FALSE & df$test2 == FALSE)

      A       B      C  test test2
-0.0586 -0.0407 0.1109 FALSE FALSE
 0.0621 -0.0621 0.0621 FALSE FALSE
-0.0452  0.0452 0.0452 FALSE FALSE
```

Thanks.

Comment: `abs(rowSums(sign(df))) == 3`

Answer (score 5):

We can use `rowSums`

```
i1 <- (!rowSums(df > 0)) & (!rowSums(df < 0))
df[i1,]
```